# Overwrite to-be-installed source file (without overwriting the orignal file in the source directory)

Tags: python, git, setuptools

I want to encode the git hash of the lastest commit at the time of installing as the output of a function in my library.

I am using a structure

```
.git/
setup.py
|- mylib/
|  - __init__.py
|  - git.py
```

whereby `git.py` contains a dummy, unconfigured, function

```py
def git():
    return None
```

At the time of installing I want to overwrite `git.py` such that it returns the hash of the latest git commit, e.g.:

```py
def git():
    return "2d04d1a10f81d24183df7622c95398d60106dfff"
```

(whereby the hash is the output of `git rev-parse HEAD` at the time of installing).

So my question:
*How can I overwrite the to-be-installed `git.py`, using setuptools, without overwriting the file in the source directory*?

---

Current work-around `setup.py`

```py
import subprocess

git_hash = subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-parse", "HEAD"]).strip().decode('UTF-8')

cmd = '''def git():
    return "{0:s}"
'''.format(git_hash)

os.rename('mylib/git.py', 'mylib/git.py.bak')

with open('mylib/git.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cmd)

setup(
    name = 'mylib',
    version = __version__,
    # ...
    packages = find_packages(),
)

os.rename('mylib/git.py.bak', 'mylib/git.py')
```

Which has the down-sight of temporarily changing `git.py` in the source directory. I'd rather leave that file completely untouched.

Comment: The current git hash of what? the mylib file?

Comment: @AvenDesta Indeed the git hash of the current commit of my library. I'll edit...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @webknjaz on setuptools' git repository (see [issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2572)) I found a solution using *setuptools_scm* that works:

### File structure

```
setup.py
|- mylib/
|  - __init__.py
|  - _version.py
```

### setup.py

```py
setup(
    name = 'mylib',
    packages = find_packages(),
    use_scm_version = {'write_to': 'mylib/_version.py'},
    setup_requires = ['setuptools_scm'],
)
```

### **init**.py

```py
from ._version import *
```

### _version.py (dummy, overwritten at install-time)

```py
version = "None"
version_tuple = (0, 0, 0, "None", "None")
```